# Oracle Apex IG : Not able to dynamically set HTML expression

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 18.

I would like my IG column to be dynamically colour-coded, have an icon based on the value of its contents.
I have that HTML code ready.

My problem is that IG will write out that HTML code instead of "escaping" it. Even the most simple HTML.

To demonstrate, I created a simple one column query for my IG, then added two HTML expression columns manually. One referring to my data (which does not display correctly). One with some random HTML expression (which does display correctly).

Query:
select ''||profile_name||'' profile_name_disp /*I will ultimately make this HTML far more complex*/
from table_a

[My IG definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/danWk.png)

[HTML expression Column referring to my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhK9D.png)

[HTML expression Column with random HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tYaQ.png)

[How my IG is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94F9p.png)

Self-help: Looked at this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4179692?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

You can't reference another column in this way. the HTML expression has to be for the same DB column.

https://community.oracle.com/message/14540517#14540517

Credit to Bernhard W